# Response.write() or .toString() (bug?) on NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, webserver

I am a trying to make a small web server for testing. I made it with NodeJS. But something unexpected happened. The webpage passed by the NodeJS server couldn't be displayed properly. But the webpage worked perfectly when I used php+Apache. When I opened the source code received at my client side, there are no observable difference. Here is my code:

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var Max = 30;
var port = process.argv[2];

var server = http.createServer( function (request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; if (pathname == "") pathname = "index.html";
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            } else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                    response.write(data.toString());
            }
            response.end();
    });
}).listen(port);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');


var sockets = {}, nextSocketId = 0;
server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var socketId = nextSocketId++;
    sockets[socketId] = socket;
    console.log('socket', socketId, 'opened');

    socket.on('close', function () {
            console.log('socket', socketId, 'closed');
            delete sockets[socketId];
    });

    socket.setTimeout(4000);
});

function anyOpen(array) {
    for (var ele in array) {
            if (ele) return true;
    }
    return false;
}


(function countDown (counter) {
    console.log(counter);
    if (anyOpen(sockets)) {
            return setTimeout(countDown, 1000, Max);
    } else if (counter > 0 ) {
            return setTimeout(countDown, 1000, counter - 1);
    };
    server.close(function () { console.log('Server closed!'); });
    for (var socketId in sockets) {
            console.log('socket', socketId, 'destroyed');
            sockets[socketId].destroy();
    }
})(Max);
```

Chatroom2-0.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
    textarea {
            width:95%;
            rows:50;
            height:80%;
    }
</style>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var str = "";
    function enter(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById("Input").value) {
                    //alert("Enter!!!!");
                    sendInput();
                    document.getElementById("Input").value = "";
            }
    };

    function updateBoard() {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("MsgBoard").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                    var textarea = document.getElementById('Output');
                    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;  
            };

            xmlhttp.open("POST","Server.php",true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("Type=Username&Content="+document.getElementById("Username").value);
    };

    function sendInput() {
            username = document.getElementById("Username").value; if (!username) username = "Gotemptyname";
            msg = document.getElementById("Input").value; if (!msg) msg = "GotNothing";
            if (msg) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xmlhttp.open("POST","Server.php",true);
                    //xmlhttp.open("POST","test.txt",true);
                    //xmlhttp.send();
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");                  
                    xmlhttp.send("Type=Message&Username="+username+"&Content="+msg);
                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
    };

</script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval('updateBoard()',1000)">
<div id="MsgBoard"></div>
<form name="UsrInput">
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["Username"]))
            echo '<input type="text" id ="Username" value="'.$_POST["Username"].'" disable>';
    else {
            header("Location: /login/index.html");
            die();
    }
?>
<input type="text" id="Input" onkeypress="enter(event)"  value="" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Users should be able to access the Chatroom2-0.php after login. The login functionality is also ok. But when I entered the Chatroom2-0.php, I got a String, next to my textbox.

> '; else { header("Location: /login/index.html"); die(); } ?>

I noticed that the string is part of my php code in the file. I don't know what's happening. I think this might have something to do with the response.write() or the data.toString() function. Maybe the function changed something in my coding? How could I solve this problem.

Anyway, I appreciate for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run php code on a nodejs server. There is no solution to this, as node is not a php interpreter, so it sees everything as html text; thus your php code appearing on the page. You need to create an entirely different html for the node project.

Comment: Oh, i should have noticed that at the first time(I am feeling stupid right now...). Thanks, alot

Comment: You're most welcome. Never feel stupid about not knowing something, so that it doesn't prevent you from asking questions in the future. The Stack exchange community thrives on people not being ashamed to ask questions when they don't know. Keep asking!